# OpenLayers: dynamic feature Information from list of Object

Tags: java, javascript, openlayers

I'm working with OpenLayers. I need to create an arrayList of object to show feature information in the map. So, I passed a list from controller to my jsp file and need to use it in js file. However, my object is undefined and i can't retrieve information. `enter code here`So i tried to create a JSON object and pass it. But, still have the same problem. I'm following this example:
http://jorix.github.io/OL-FeaturePopups/examples/feature-popups.html

map.js

```js
// Projections
// -----------
var sphericalMercatorProj = new OpenLayers.Projection('EPSG:900913');
var geographicProj = new OpenLayers.Projection('EPSG:4326');

// Vector layers
// -------------
// Sprinters: layer with different attributes.
var sprintersLayer = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector('Sprinters (translated labels)', {
    styleMap: new OpenLayers.StyleMap({
        externalGraphic: 'resources/img/mobile-loc.png',
        graphicOpacity: 1.0,
        graphicWith: 16,
        graphicHeight: 26,
        graphicYOffset: -26
    })
});
sprintersLayer.addFeatures(getSprintersFeatures());

// Create map
// ----------
var map = new OpenLayers.Map({
    div: 'map',
    theme: null,
    projection: sphericalMercatorProj,
    displayProjection: geographicProj,
    units: 'm',
    numZoomLevels: 18,
    maxResolution: 156543.0339,
    maxExtent: new OpenLayers.Bounds(
        -20037508.34, -20037508.34, 20037508.34, 20037508.34
    ),
    controls: [
        new OpenLayers.Control.Attribution(),
        new OpenLayers.Control.Navigation(),
        new OpenLayers.Control.PanZoom(),
        new OpenLayers.Control.LayerSwitcher()
    ],
    layers: [
        new OpenLayers.Layer.OSM('OpenStreetMap', null),
        sprintersLayer
    ],
    center: new OpenLayers.LonLat(0, 0),
    zoom: 2
});


// Sprinters features
// ------------------
function getSprintersFeatures() {
 
 console.info("in getSprintersFeatures ");
 var features= [];
 var geojson = { 'type': 'FeatureCollection',
      'features': features};
  
    // Think here is my problem.
 var list=eval(document.getElementById("${chaine}"));
 
 for(var i=0;i< list.length;i++){
  
  var longit=list[i][0];
  var latitud=list[i][1];
  var time=list[i][2];
  
  var list= new Array();
  
  var geom={};
  geom.type='Point';
  geom.coordinates=[longit, latitud];
  
  var prop={};
  prop.Longitude=longit;
  prop.Latitude= latitud;
  prop.Time=time;
  
  var elem={};
  var resultTab=[];
  elem.type='Feature';
  elem.geometry= geom ;
  elem.properties= prop ;
  
  features.push(elem);
  console.info(elem);
 }
 
 var reader = new OpenLayers.Format.GeoJSON();
    return reader.read(geojson);
}
```

```html
<c:forEach items="${listFromController}" var="cor" varStatus="stat">
 <c:choose>
  <c:when test="${stat.count == 1}">
          <c:set var="chaine" value="${chaine}[[${cor.longitude},${cor.latitude},${cor.time}]" />
        </c:when>
        <c:otherwise>
          <c:set var="chaine" value="${chaine},[${cor.longitude},${cor.latitude},${cor.time}]" />
        </c:otherwise>
    </c:choose>
</c:forEach>
<c:set var="chaine" value="${chaine}]"/>

<div id="map" class="mws-panel-body"> </div>
<script src="resources/map.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is difficult to parse JSON objects using the navigator. So to deal with it, we must use a function to create JSON objects. Then, we can use it with jQuery ajax. 
We have to inject this bean in spring context and then create our JSON function:

```js
<bean id="cnManager"  
    class="org.springframework.web.accept.ContentNegotiationManagerFactoryBean">  
  <property name="favorPathExtension" value="true"/>  
  <property name="ignoreAcceptHeader" value="true" />  
  <property name="defaultContentType" value="text/html" />  
  <property name="useJaf" value="false"/>  
  
  <property name="mediaTypes">  
    <map>  
   <entry key="html" value="text/html" />  
   <entry key="json" value="application/json" />  
   <entry key="xml" value="application/xml" />  
    </map>  
  </property>  
 </bean>
```

```html
@RequestMapping(value = "/list.json", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = { "application/json" })
 @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
 public @ResponseBody
 List<Mesure> list() {
  return s.list();
 }
```